# What is the difference between an object data source and a SQL datasource?

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between an object datasource and SQL datasource?

Also, what is the difference between DataReader and DataAdapter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For the first question see: [SqlDataSource vs ObjectDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207295/sqldatasource-vs-objectdatasource)

for the second question: [ADO.NET Question: When to use DataReader, DataAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693788/ado-net-question-when-to-use-datareader-dataadapter)