# Not able to access fields with group by and multiple joins with linq

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I want to list only those categories with average which have difference in their records.

This difference exist in 2 tables:**TestOperation,TestOperationDifference**

I want to calculate average of below 3 fields :

```
TestOperation:DiffPerc

If DiffPerc  < 100 
    "Difference is there and take value of DiffPerc to calculate average"
else 
    "Dont take that record"


TestOperationDifference:DiffPerc,DiffRec
If DiffPerc  < 100 
    "Difference is there and take value of DiffPerc and DiffRec to calculate average"
else 
    "Dont take that record"




finalAverage=(
                   Average(TestOperation.DiffPerc) 
                    + Average(TestOperationDifference.DiffPerc)
                    + Average(TestOperationDifference.DiffRec)
              )/3
```

Output like this:

```
[0]=Mobile 
    Electronics
    FinalAverage=30.00
[1]=Shoes 
    Sports
    FinalAverage=70.00
.
.
.
```

My Code:

```
public class Category
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Variants> Variants { get; set; }
        }

  public class Variants
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public int CategoryId { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<SubVariants> SubVariants { get; set; }
            public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        }

        public class SubVariants
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int VariantId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public virtual Variants Variants { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<TestOperationDifference> TestOperationDifference { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<TestOperationDifference> TestOperationDifference1 { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<TestOperation> TestOperation { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<TestOperation> TestOperation1 { get; set; }
        }

        public class Test
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Version { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<TestOperation> TestOperation { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<TestOperationDifference> TestOperationDifference { get; set; }
        }

        public class TestOperation
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> TestId { get; set; }
            public int SourceSubVariantId { get; set; }
            public int TargetSubVariantId { get; set; }
            public decimal DiffPerc { get; set; }
            public virtual SubVariants SubVariants { get; set; }
            public virtual SubVariants SubVariants1 { get; set; }
            public virtual Test Test { get; set; }
        }

        public class TestOperationDifference
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> TestId { get; set; }
            public int SourceSubVariantId { get; set; }
            public int TargetSubVariantId { get; set; }
            public decimal DiffPerc { get; set; }
            public decimal DiffRec { get; set; }
            public virtual SubVariants SubVariants { get; set; }
            public virtual SubVariants SubVariants1 { get; set; }
            public virtual Test Test { get; set; }
        }
```

My Query:

```
 var query = from cat in context.Category
             join v in context.Variants on cat.Id equals v.CategoryId
             join sv in context.SubVariants on v.Id equals sv.VariantId
             join to in context.TestOperation on sv.Id equals to.SourceSubVariantId
join tod in context.TestOperationDifference on sv.Id equals tod.SourceSubVariantId
             where 
              (to.DiffPerc < 100) 
                 ||
              (tod.DiffPerc < 100 )
               group cat by new {catid = cat.Id} into grp 
              select new 
              {
                subcategoryname=grp. //not getting property here                 
                ParentCategoryName=grp.
                FinalAverage=    
              }
```

But here in above query when I am trying to access subcategory name then I 
am not able to access it.

[Demo Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SczwQ7)

Comment: Why are you putting parenthesis when you want to create a new anonymous class?

Comment: @dotctor:Ok updated my question

Comment: You have grouped your query into `grp`. You have `grp.Key` which has `catid` property. Which property are you looking for?

Comment: @dotctor:If you will see my expected output you will see that i want Subcategory name and parentcategory name but only those subcategory which have corresponding records in those 2 tables(TestOperation,TestOperationDifference) but i need to go to this tables through variants and subvariant because i have subvariants Ids in this 2 tables

Comment: I think you misunderstood the concept of `group` in linq. If it helps you can access a sample of your grouping by `grp.First()`

Comment: @dotctor:But i think that do i really need to link all this tables.What you think??

Comment: I think you should read more about grouping and it's usage.

Answer (score 3):

The basic query should look like this

```
 var query = (from cat in category
                         join v in variants on cat.Id equals v.CategoryId
                         join sv in subVariants on v.Id equals sv.VariantId
                         into grp
                         select new { id = cat.Id, subvariant = v.SubVariants, name = cat.Name, type = v.Type})
                         .GroupBy(x => new {id = x.id, subvariant = x.subvariant});
```

The you need to apply the testOperations  and testOperationDifferences to the query.

Comment: Variant table will contain subcategory Ids and not the Parent category Ids

Comment: Each join must produce some output.  Your join of category and variants doesn't produce any valid results.

Comment: Sorry actually i forgot to add category data that is why you were not getting output.Check updated fiddle now

Answer (score 2):

Well that happens because `grp` is the instance of `IGrouping` which is the collection. As you probably already guess you need to access some element of the collection to get the `Name` property of the `Category` or you can group your collection of `Category` by the `Name` and the `Id` (if it makes sense in your case), thus you could access it using `grp.Key.Name`